# NetworkAvailabilityChanged not working with mono

Tags: mono

I've got an small program that is written in VB.NET and compiled with .NET4. When I run it on win7 and unplug my network cable, I have an event. when I run the program on Ubuntu V12.10 and mono, I do not have any reaction when the network cable is unplugged?

Does anyone has some suggestions or solution?

I use the applicationevents.vb form in VB.Net 2012 with the trigger:

> **Private Sub MyApplication_NetworkChange() Handles Me.NetworkAvailabilityChanged**

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the calls/events in the Windows and Linux kernel are totally different and (most likely) not portable. I would suggest to review your program. Also, I would use Network Manager instead.

Comment: @Braiam I don't see what this has to do with kernels; a CLR implementation (like Mono), similar to a Java VM, should abstract over all that. I see no *a priori* reason why the event shouldn't be raised in Mono.

Comment: Describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org) for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

From vbforums, there are two possible answers, from [jmcilhinney](http://www.vbforums.com/member.php?58941-jmcilhinney&s=77f32261dd581c788ee0b157aad46f90). [One says](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?732521-Application-Event-NetworkAvailabilityChanged-not-working&s=77f32261dd581c788ee0b157aad46f90&p=4498085&viewfull=1#post4498085):

> I'm not 100% sure but I think it likely that that NetworkAvailabilityChanged event is presumably a wrapper for the NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged event. The documentation for that event says:
>
> > The NetworkChange class raises NetworkAvailabilityChanged events when the availability of the network changes. The network is available when at least one network interface is marked "up" and is not a tunnel or loopback interface.
>
> Presumably you have at least one non-tunnel or loopback network interface marked as "up", even when you unplug your network cable.

and [the other](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?732521-Application-Event-NetworkAvailabilityChanged-not-working&s=77f32261dd581c788ee0b157aad46f90&p=4498107&viewfull=1#post4498107):

> My guess would be that it uses a Windows-specific API under the hood that is not available on Linux and either has no analogue or at least it hasn't been implemented in Mono.

There is also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14741475/792066) in StackOverflow that has no answer still. I was reading the [source code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net.NetworkInformation/NetworkChange.cs) of mono, trying to figure out this issue. Although it has a `LinuxNetworkChange ()` function, I didn't saw what the problem is (and I'm not too familiarized with mono).

Either way, since you didn't say that the program was firing an error, it could be that it wasn't catch or mono doesn't listen at all for it. A more robust search lies ahead.